# Can this formula be made to spill?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is a very cut down version of my project.

I have a table of data calculated from daily timesheets through PowerQuery.
This represents the periods of sickness each employee has had over the last twelve months.

I run a bunch of other queries after this table bringing in the employee name, the facility they work at and their calculated [Bradford Score](https://www.bradfordfactorcalculator.com/)

**Table: RollingSick**
[image]

Finally I end up with a sheet containing formula so I can filter by facility to send to various managers.
Columns `G:M` in the image below would be a spilled range, although for my example it's just the first column that's spilling.

[image]

Next to the table above I want to add the dates for each absence period next to each employee.  The idea being that the manager can then inform me to remove certain periods from the scoring as the matter is dealt with.

This formula will do that, but I'd need to drag down for each row in my spilled range.  I haven't decided how I want to present it yet, so there's two return values.

```
=LET(SickDates,TEXT(FILTER(FILTER(RollingSick,RollingSick[Emp No]=G2),{0,0,0,1,1}),"dd-mm-yy"),
          JoinDates, INDEX(SickDates,,1) & " to " & INDEX(SickDates,,2),
          Return1, TEXTJOIN(" | ",FALSE,JoinDates),
          Return2, TRANSPOSE(JoinDates),
          Return1)
```

[image]

I'd like this to spill down if possible, but can't figure it out.
A few of my attempts:

*Returns the same dates on each row.*

```
=IF(G2#="","",
          LET(SickDates,TEXT(FILTER(FILTER(RollingSick,RollingSick[Emp No]=G2),{0,0,0,1,1}),"dd-mm-yy"),
          JoinDates, INDEX(SickDates,,1) & " to " & INDEX(SickDates,,2),
          Return1, TEXTJOIN(" | ",FALSE,JoinDates),
          Return2, TRANSPOSE(JoinDates),
          Return1))
```

*Returns #N/A*

```
=LET(SickDates,TEXT(FILTER(FILTER(RollingSick,RollingSick[Emp No]=INDEX(G2#,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(G2#)))),{0,0,0,1,1}),"dd-mm-yy"),
          JoinDates, INDEX(SickDates,,1) & " to " & INDEX(SickDates,,2),
          Return1, TEXTJOIN(" | ",FALSE,JoinDates),
          Return2, TRANSPOSE(JoinDates),
          Return1)
```

*Only returns first row:*

```
=LET(SickDates,TEXT(FILTER(FILTER(RollingSick,RollingSick[Emp No]=INDEX(G2#,ROW()-ROW($G$1))),{0,0,0,1,1}),"dd-mm-yy"),
          JoinDates, INDEX(SickDates,,1) & " to " & INDEX(SickDates,,2),
          Return1, TEXTJOIN(" | ",FALSE,JoinDates),
          Return2, TRANSPOSE(JoinDates),
          Return1)
```

Comment: I do not have time to recreate your data or really test it but somthing like: `=BYROW(G2#,LAMBDA(a,LET(SickDates,TEXT(FILTER(FILTER(RollingSick,RollingSick[Emp No]=a),{0,0,0,1,1}),"dd-mm-yy"),
          JoinDates, INDEX(SickDates,,1) & " to " & INDEX(SickDates,,2),
          Return1, TEXTJOIN(" | ",FALSE,JoinDates),
          Return2, TRANSPOSE(JoinDates),
          Return1) ))`  Again I have not tested this and am not sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner.  Works perfectly for `Return1` (TextJoin and returning each row in a single cell).  `Return2` returns more than one value so BYROW is returning a #CALC! error.  Any ideas before I start Frankensteining something?

Comment: sorry, I would need to do some testing myself.  So not sure.

Comment: @ScottCraner Have gone with your original version - put it as an answer to get the accepted tick. :)